# How to wait for callback function return?

Tags: go, callback

I have the following code:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  player.Exec(command, func(response map[string]interface{}){
    if response["statusCode"]==float64(0) { // ok
      w.Write([]byte(response["statusMessage"].(string)))
      player.SendMessage("<b>"+response["statusMessage"].(string)+"</b>")
      fmt.Println("playerExec: "+time.Now().Format("20060102150405"))
    } else { // failed to process
      w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest) // 400
      w.Write([]byte(response["statusMessage"].(string)))
      player.SendMessage(response["statusMessage"].(string))
    }
  })
  // Time.Sleep(Time.Seconds*2)
  fmt.Println("cmd: "+time.Now().Format("20060102150405"))   
})
```

processing of `player.Exec()` takes some time (since it initiates WebSocket connection), so the callback function is called after some time (see proofs below). It is late, so I see the following error:

> http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from main.main.func1.1

Also, when I open the '/' page in the browser, I see no content. 
If I add `Time.Sleep()` to my code (see the commented line), then I see the content.
The Exec() code is [here](https://github.com/Sandertv/mcwss/blob/master/player.go#L133).

The log shows the following -

```
cmd: 20200612192659
playerExec: 20200612192659
```

Is there any way to wait for the callback function return?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `sync.WaitGroup` as follows:

```
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  wg.Add(1)  // add a waitgroup before calling the async function
  player.Exec(command, func(response map[string]interface{}){
    defer wg.Done()  // release when this function returns
    if response["statusCode"]==float64(0) { // ok
      w.Write([]byte(response["statusMessage"].(string)))
      player.SendMessage("<b>"+response["statusMessage"].(string)+"</b>")
      fmt.Println("playerExec: "+time.Now().Format("20060102150405"))
    } else { // failed to process
      w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest) // 400
      w.Write([]byte(response["statusMessage"].(string)))
      player.SendMessage(response["statusMessage"].(string))
    }
  })
  wg.Wait()  // this will block until all the resources are released
  fmt.Println("cmd: "+time.Now().Format("20060102150405"))   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from main.main.func1.1

You will see this if you do a `WriteHeader` after you have already written something to the response via `Write`. That's why WriteHeader is extra or `superfluous`.

As of waiting for your exec to be done, you can use waitgroup in your closure.

`wg.Wait()` will wait until your exec callback has returned

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  wg.Add(1)
  player.Exec(command, func(response map[string]interface{}){
    defer wg.Done()
    if response["statusCode"]==float64(0) { // ok
      w.Write([]byte(response["statusMessage"].(string)))
      player.SendMessage("<b>"+response["statusMessage"].(string)+"</b>")
      fmt.Println("playerExec: "+time.Now().Format("20060102150405"))
    } else { // failed to process
      w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest) // 400
      w.Write([]byte(response["statusMessage"].(string)))
      player.SendMessage(response["statusMessage"].(string))
    }
  })

  wg.Wait()

  // Time.Sleep(Time.Seconds*2)
  fmt.Println("cmd: "+time.Now().Format("20060102150405"))   
})
```